# Zend Framework: Navigation XML and duplicate page elements

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, navigation

In XML I'd normal expect the following to be perfectly valid and navigable in a meaningful way using something like PHP's DomDocument:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>    
  <page>
    <name>Home</name>
  </page>
  <page>
    <name>Log in</name>
  </page>
</configdata>
```

This is not the case when using `Zend_Navigation`. Each `<page>` element needs to have a unique name, so you would need to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>    
  <page_home>
    <name>Home</name>
  </page_home>
  <page_log_in>
    <name>Log in</name>
  </page_log_in>
</configdata>
```

This works, but is very annoying. I'd much rather have multiple page elements which can have the same name and can be easily copy and pasted when creating many pages for navigation.

Why does each one need a unique name?

Is there a way of not having to have a unique name?

**@Charles**

Yes, the following code is used to read in the navigaion XML

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml');

$container = new Zend_Navigation($config);

Zend_Registry::set("navigation", $container);
```

**@Gordon**

Good question...I used to use this method, but wanted another way that was easier to update and read. The array notation does solve the issue I have but it isn't an easy way of writing out the navigation for a site, especially when there are nested elements. XML is much easy to read and make sense of than PHP's arrays.

Granted this is my own opinion and it is a slower way of storing and parsing navigation data.

Comment: Is this configuration provided by Zend_Config, by chance?

Comment: @Charles - yes, see my edited answer for code

Comment: @Carles - I think I know where your going with this....should I not be using Zend_Config as this results in the unique names being required?

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using XML over the [Array notation that is faster and doesnt have those issues](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.containers.html)?

Comment: Hi Gordon - see my edit.

Comment: I was actually going to just recommend using the INI format instead, as it'd make much more sense when you consider the naming format they're imposing.

Comment: Looking at the docs, doesn't that require a unique element too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the first XML structure, because `Zend_Navigation` uses the Tag definition to create a part of the "Route". If you want use an another type of XML structure, you probably have to extend `Zend_Navigation` with your own parsing process.

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml');
$container new My_Navigation($config);
```

Another way would be to create a class to parse and modify the XML document before sending it to `Zend_Navigation`.

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml');
$navigationStructure = new My_Navigation_Parser($config);
$container new My_Navigation($navigationStructure);
```

Comment: Thanks Akarun +1 - just to clarify - 'Zend_Navigation uses the Tag definition to create a part of the Route', the Tag you mention is the `<page>` and `<page_home>` parts of my XML? These need to be unique in order for Zend_Navigation to create the unique routes for each page?

Comment: Not exactly for the route (my mistake), but to identify the correct route are used by the router. for Sample when you use a Navigation menu, it's used to mark some element as "Active". You know ? 
And, if you don't have any "Route" defined in your menu element, Zend use the name to create the link, indeed.